# Process index of l3doc file / of .dtx file

Tags: indexing, expl3, docstrip, l3doc

I understand that `.dtx` files are a way to both document and implement a package in one file together.

Also, in newer versions, usually `pdflatex package.dtx` should typeset the documentation.

I wanted to try this for some examples to check out such `.dtx` files, but I am unable to do this properly for the `LaTeX3` kernel files.

In particular, getting `l3prop.dtx` from

https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/195f85d5c8df68ca32ac0c7d5559efa27f0fa63d/l3kernel/l3prop.dtx

and running `pdflatex` on it produces the documentation with missing Index.
So after running `makeindex l3prop.idx` on the generated aux file as usual, and running `pdflatex l3prop.dtx` again, I get the error

```
LaTeX Error: Text for \verb command ended by end of line.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4     \subitem \verb*&
                        
?
```

and in fact the corresponding `l3prop.ind` contains this code and does not seem to be correct (in fact I cannot find a terminating * in it for the `\verb*` command).

`latexmk l3prop.dtx` also does not seem to do the job, it runs into the same error.

I also produced a sample `.tex` document, just contain a minimal `l3doc` class as a `.tex` file, and here also typesetting the index with `\PrintIndex` goes wrong in the same way, so it seems to have to do with the `l3doc` class.

So my question would be on **how to process this `.dtx` file - or more general a `l3doc` document to properly typeset the index as well**.

I assume it is just a question of calling the correct index generation programs / script etc that I do not know of.

Comment: You'll probably need a specific `.ist` file for the kernel `.dtx` files.

Comment: And you do: `makeindex -s gind.ist l3prop.idx` then it compiles as it should (I looked in the manual for `ltxdoc` which is probably the predecessor of `l3doc`)

Comment: @daleif thanks for pointing out the mistake, I corrected the question`

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks

Comment: Now a days you just run TeX on it `tex l3doc.dtx`. But it depends on the setup, some still come with a `.dtx` and a `.ins` and running LaTeX on the `.ins` produces the `.sty` or `.cls`

Comment: @daleif Sounds like an answer to me

Comment: Just an aside: `\verb` has a starred form, so `\verb*abc*` is *wrong* and would result in the same error if placed in an otherwise empty line, the delimiter is the symbol after the `*`.

Comment: @Skillmon oh, I also didn't know that, neat to know

Comment: @daleif Feel free to repost your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever a document is written in `ltxdoc` or the new `l3doc` the index needs a driver/configuration. If we look in the manual for `ltxdoc` we see that the following is the normal recommended call to `makeindex` for this type of documents:

```
makeindex -s gind.ist file.idx
```

Comment: How can I register this as a compile command in TeXstudio ?